# How to change default home page path ' ' to a different route if there is data in local storage in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a default page route location that I want to change if I have some data saved in local storage.
For Example :
{path: '', redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
I want to change this to /user if I have data stored from previous results.

Comment: You have to use router.navigate(['/user'])...

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with a guard, since the canActivate method has *UrlTree* as a return value, which means we can not just protect some route but also redirect to another.
This is how to do it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private myLocalStorageWrapperService: LocalStorageWrapperService,
   private router: Router) {}
  
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (this.myLocalStorageWrapperService.hasData()) {
        // redirect to user route
        return this.router.parseUrl("user");
    } else {
       // continue as is
       return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Replace *myLocalStorageWrapperService* with your implementation of the *window.localStorage* wrapper or just remove it and use *window.localStorage* directly.
You would use it inside you route definition:

```
{ 
  path: '',
  canActivate: [RedirectGuard]
  redirectTo: "/home", 
  pathMatch: "full" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe your first datas Object or Array in your component.ts, did you try to use this inside your subscribe ? :

```
 if (this.array.length > 0){
        this.router.navigate(['/route-name']);
      }
```

(if `> 0` doesn't work, try `> 1`)

If you try this, you must inject the router in your constructor parameters to use `navigate()`.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


  constructor(private router: Router,...
```